# What is bundle.js.gz file in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, webpack

I am using ng-cli for my application. when i run ng build --prod, i got two files main.budle.js & main.bundle.js.gz. what is the second one & what is the benefit of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP transfer between server and client almost always uses compression. In most cases this is gzip.

So what matters for transfer times is not the size of your `bundle.js` but the size of `bundle.js.gz` as content is practically always sent in its gzip compressed form.

When `bundle.js` is requested, the server gzips it on the fly and puts it on the wire. So gzip is run on every request, which is inefficient for static content.

Also gzip's performance drops significantly with the level of compression ([check out this article](https://www.rootusers.com/gzip-vs-bzip2-vs-xz-performance-comparison/)). Using the highest compression level possible isn't efficient if at all possible on-the-fly.
A properly configured webserver would send `bundle.js.gz` when a gzipped version of `bundle.js` is requested, so you could use the highest compression level gzip can provide.

In my opinion, the performance bonus of this is negligible unless your server mainly provides static content that can be compressed ahead-of-time. For a small application, with static content and API being served from the same machine, there should be practically no impact.

Comment: Well Explained. Thanks :)

Comment: @user32 I have an angular2  app using app.js.gz but the browser doesnt do anything with the file. I made a question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047617/angular2-gzip-issue-when-i-run-my-app

Comment: @user32 I basically just want the app.js.gz file to work with the browser so that my angular2 app runs. I host with firebase and use cloudflare. Do I need to do some setting changes?

Comment: @AngularM Just check if your server supports gzip.

Answer (score 1):

Gzipped folders are meant for server. Your server must have such configuration for that. Write it in your server conf files so that they could send gzipped folders.

[image]
[image]